# Custom id for "at" jobs

Tags: ubuntu, at

I've been using `at` to schedule emails to be sent at a specific date and time. Problem is that the command that I wish `at` to execute should take the job id as a parameter hence why I should be the one generating them. This is aside from the fact that what `at` uses aren't id's at all, rather counts that gets incremented automatically which means that I have to worry about when they will reset.

My main inquiry is creating new at jobs with custom id's. Meaning that while creating jobs with the following command: `echo "touch file" | at now + 1 minute`, if it could instead be something like this: `echo "touch file" | at -i <custom-id> now + 1 minute`. So that when I hit `atq`, I will find: `<custom-id> Mon Feb 24 19:00:00 2020 a user`.

So, is there a way to give jobs custom when I create them with `at` OR if there are any open source alternatives that scale better?

Comment: I'm sorry Joe I don't understand what it is that you're trying to achieve here. Why doesn't `at` scale for you?

Comment: [FreeBSD code](https://searchcode.com/file/457821/usr.bin/at/at.c) has `jobno = (1+jobno) % 0xfffff; /* 2^20 jobs enough? */`, which allows for approximately one million concurrently queued jobs.

Comment: My main inquiry is creating new `at` jobs with custom id's. Meaning that while creating jobs with the following command: `echo "touch file" | at now + 1 minute`, if it could instead be something like this: `echo "touch file" | at -i <custom-id> now + 1 minute`. So that when I hit `atq`, I will find:
<custom-id> Mon Feb 24 19:00:00 2020 a user.

Comment: As for the scalability of `at`, it's true that it supports a large number of simultaneous jobs but if what if those jobs are resource heavy, it could potentially lead to the low availability of the server, not to mention that `at` lacks a ton of features. What if I wanted to delete jobs? I would need to have the id of said job which is a pain to obtain (recovering it from the warning generated by the above command seems kinda hacky). I now need to have the id before I launch the command which looks impossible after a day of reading the docs and searching around.

Comment: I also would like some error handling to schedule another job in case of a network outage.

Comment: No, `at` does not support a large number of simultaneous jobs

Comment: @roaima I meant queued jobs but when you have multiple ones scheduled for the same date and time, they will run in rapid succession which could be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the job number for an `at` submission with this sort of code. The example submits a job that simply sleeps for five minutes, so you will obviously have to adjust that. The output from an `at` submission is like `job 1175 at Mon Feb 24 18:28:00 2020` and the `grep` command matches on this to extract the job number

```
job=$( echo "sleep 300" | at now 2>&1 | grep -oP 'job\s+\K\d+' )
echo "The job identifier is $job"
```

There is no way to identify the job number before it has been submitted to `at`.

Comment: Are there any third-party open-source tools that does the same as `at` but offer at least the features that I mentioned: create jobs with custom id's (preferably on that integrates with a database like mysql) and error handling in case the scheduled command failed or if the server experienced a downtime during the time a batch of jobs where suppose to be executed.

Comment: I don't know of any. What would you want to happen if a server went down - consider queued jobs and jobs that are currently executing